# How to calculate the number of items that can fit into a tree

Tags: combinatorics, trees

Wondering how to calculate the number of items that can fit into a tree.

For example, say at each level of a tree you can have 10 children (aka 10 different "types"). Say you're only considering trees that are 10 levels deep. The question is, the generic way of solving this so I can do it for any tree with `n` number of children at each level, and `m` levels deep.

For example, a real data tree might look like this:

```
                      top
    0         1    2 3       4       5    6 7 8
1 3 4 5 6    2 3          3 4 5 6   5 8
```

Where the numbers are from 0-9 to account for the 10 children per level. I would like to know *how many nodes can possibly fit into the tree*, what the equation is for this. Basically, the maximum number of nodes in a specific model of a tree, specifying the number of children per node, and the number of levels in the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of nodes at level $m$ is certainly $n^m$ (assuming root is considered level 0). Therefore, the maximum number of nodes for a $m$-deep tree is
$$
f(m,n) = \sum_{k=0}^m n^k = \frac{n^{m+1}-1}{n-1}
$$
using a geometric series.

**Example** Testing this out on a binary tree (at most 2 children per node), you get $f(m,2) = 2^{m+1}-1$, as expected.

Comment: Just to help me better understand, wondering if the `k` isn't an exponent, it is just the current level of the iteration.

Comment: The sum should start at $k=0$.

Comment: @NickD of course, thanks -- corrected

Comment: @LancePollard yes, you count level by level, and the current level index is denoted by $k$